# Remove ATI video card and install Asus/Nvidia 210 silent

Tags: video, hardware

What is the correct procedure for removing an ATI HD2400Pro and installing an ASUS 210 silent? Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

1. If installed, remove the proprietary AMD driver.
2. Shut down, and swap the cards.
3. Boot up.

Hope that works.

Comment: don't forget to add making sure the power supply is off, or if the power supply does not have a kill switch - unplugged, and use a static wrist strap, or the very least hold the cards by the edges, seems trivial but very important.